# apache pig script with time interval

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to SUM the RW column for each port hourly

```
Time     ID  Name               RW        
-------- --- -------         ----------
14:57:01 000 Port0            1340
14:57:01 001 Port1             13

14:58:01 000 Port0             864
14:58:01 001 Port1             36

14:59:01 000 Port0            1394
14:59:01 001 Port1             22

15:57:01 000 Port0            1340
15:57:01 001 Port1             13

15:58:01 000 Port0            864
15:58:01 001 Port1             36

15:59:01 000 Port0            1394
15:59:01 001 Port1             22
.
.
.

20:57:01 000 Port0            1340
20:57:01 001 Port1             13

20:58:01 000 Port0            864
20:58:01 001 Port1            36

20:59:01 000 Port0            1394
20:59:01 001 Port1             22
```

My script is

```
data = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (time:chararray, id:chararray, name:chararray, read:int, write:int, rw:int);
runs = FOREACH data GENERATE time, name, rw;
```

How to

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to generate a new column from the time column called hours,then group by hours,port name and then get the sum for each grouping.

```
data = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (time:chararray, id:chararray, name:chararray, read:int, write:int, rw:int);
runs = FOREACH data GENERATE GetHour((timestamp)time) as hour, name, rw;
grouped = GROUP runs by (hour,name);
port_total = FOREACH grouped GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (hour,name),SUM(data.rw);
DUMP port_total;
```

Comment: I got :
`Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.GetHour as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.`

I dont know if it is mandatory that the time format in my data file have to be in the form of "datetime" 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss' or not?

Comment: @agamil You are loading time as chararray. Cast it to datetime.I've edited the answer.